# Only able to recover offline Heroku app by removing Rack::Timeout

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, rack, unicorn

Heroku app using Ruby/Sinatra/Unicorn crashed recently and even though I restarted the app and scaled up the dynos, the app would continue to timeout, even if I was calling an empty function.

I saw the following Rack::Timeout error in my logs, so I tried removing Rack::Timeout from my app, which after a 2min pause brought the app back to life and now runs in <1s.

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-timeout-0.2.4/lib/rack/timeout.rb:83:incall:
Request older than 30000ms. (Rack::Timeout::RequestExpiryError)
```

Heroku has said that removing Rack::Timeout is not recommended for apps running on Unicorn, so is there a better solution to this? Why is the app not resuming after a restart?

For reference, here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
#gem 'rack-timeout'
gem 'sinatra'
gem "pg"
gem 'activerecord'
gem 'activesupport'
gem 'sinatra-activerecord'
gem 'unicorn'
group :production do
    gem 'newrelic_rpm'
end
```

Here is my config.ru

```
#require "rack-timeout"
#use Rack::Timeout
#Rack::Timeout.timeout = (ENV["RACK_TIMEOUT"] || 10).to_i

use Rack::Deflater

require './web'
run Sinatra::Application
use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
```

And here is my unicorn.rb:

```
# config/unicorn.rb
worker_processes (ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 3).to_i
timeout (ENV['WEB_TIMEOUT'] || 15).to_i
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
    Signal.trap 'TERM' do
        puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
        Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
    end

    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
    Signal.trap 'TERM' do
        puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
    end

    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Comment: is a 6.5yr old version of ruby necessary for this app?

Comment: Ruby 2+ seemed to cause problems initially with Heroku/Postgres, but it has been sometime since I re-evaluated it.

Comment: We got the exact same problem on one of our development application. We got the error message "Request older than xxx ms", even when the request is done immediatly, by watching the logs in live. I will create an issue on Github. BTW we are in Ruby 2.2x and Rails 4.2. There is something related on Chrome browser, because when I open the same request on Safari or Firefox, there is not such problem. There is something related at this place in the rack-timeout gem : https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/rack-timeout/0.2.4/symbols/Rack::Timeout::RequestTimeoutError#line=74